# What does the 'undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)' error in my ruby code mean?

Tags: ruby

newbie here. So I was coding along on youtube and found the following error 'undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)'. I know the code works because it was able to run in the video but when I tried to run it, I received the error.

The following is my code:

```
def caesar_cipher(string, num)
  alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
  caesar = ""
  string.each_char do |letter|
    if letter == " "
      caesar += " "
    else
      old_idx = alphabet.find_index(letter)
      new_idx = (old_idx + num) % alphabet.count
      caesar += alphabet[new_idx]
    end
  end
  caesar
end

puts caesar_cipher("What a string!",5)
```

What could be causing the error? Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: The function only works for characters in `alphabet`, i.e., `'a'..'z'`. So when a space is looked up in `alphabet`, it cannot be found and so `old_idx` is `nil`.

Comment: your first letter `w` is capital it won't be found in  `a..z` that's why it is giving error, either transform whole string in small letters before processing or change conditions a little bit

Comment: Thanks, I see..really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function only works `'a'..'z'` as @Jeremty mentioned, so `W` and `!` will be `nil`.If you want to keep every none alphabet char, the following code maybe help.

```rb
def caesar_cipher(string, num)
  alphabet = [*'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z']
  caesar = ""
  string.each_char do |letter|
    old_idx = alphabet.find_index(letter)
    if old_idx.nil?
      caesar += letter
    else
      new_idx = (old_idx + num) % alphabet.count
      caesar += alphabet[new_idx]
    end
  end

  caesar
end

puts caesar_cipher("What a string!",5)
```

Comment: nit: might as well just check if old_idx is `nil`, rather than searching `alphabet` twice. Also, this version will rewrite some uppercase letters to lowercase and vice versa, which may not be intentional.